# How can a Perl subroutine report the line that called it?

Tags: perl, subroutine, error-reporting, die

I am writing a Perl pipeline, a script that calls various other programs and manages passing data from one to the other. The script (call it `pipeline.pl`) and the various sub-scripts it manages all share a list of common subroutines defined in `subroutines.ph` and included via a `require subroutines.ph` directive.

One of these is a function whose job is to exit printing an error message (the actual subroutine also does some other jobs, but they're not relevant here; no, I am not reinventing `die()`):

```perl
## subroutines.ph
sub errorDie
{
    my ($errMsg) = @_;
    ## various other cleanup tasks here
    die($errMsg);
}
1;
```

And, in `pipeline.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 
require 'subroutines.ph';

errorDie("foo")
```

Running the script above results in:

```
foo at subroutines.ph line 5.
```

Is it possible to have it instead report something like:

```
foo at pipelines.pl line 4.
```

So, instead of reporting the line the `die()` was found on, it should report the line of the original script where the `errorDie` subroutine was called from. I know I can do this by including the line in the `$errMsg` variable, but that is fragile and cumbersome. Can this be done automatically? Can a subroutine defined in an external file detect where it was called from?

Comment: Did you hear about Carp. I think it is what you need to use. See this link - http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html

Comment: @Mohit oh wow. Yes, I knew about `carp` but didn't know it did this automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon: That's pretty much *all* it does!

Comment: @Borodin fine, rub it in why don't'cha :P Indeed, that is pretty much all it does. For some reason, despite having known about it for years, I had never twigged to that very obvious fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the point of [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp)'s `croak`.

`Pkg.pm`:

```
package Pkg;

use Carp qw( croak );

sub some_func {
    my ($cmd, $param) = @_;

    $cmd eq 'encode' || $cmd eq 'decode'
       or croak("Invalid command \"$cmd\"");

    # ...
}

1;
```

`a.pl`:

```
use Pkg;

Pkg::some_func('foo', 'bar');
```

Output:

```
Invalid command "foo" at a.pl line 3.
```

Answer (score 7):

There is `caller` , to do this:
https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html

```
my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
```

gives you the information you need.

However, as you are talking about debugging generally, you can get a complete backtrace from `carp`, as mentioned already.

Comment: Sorry for switching the accept to the other answer but since they provided an actual example, it seems best to have that one come up on the top of the page. Thanks though!

Comment: That's enough to make a simple log file with code line number